# Placement of windows from another app inside of MS Word

Tags: vba, delphi, winapi, ms-word, ole-automation

My question is how to place a window belonging to our win32 application inside of MS Word, when Word has been set as the parent of that window using Windows API `SetParent(HandleOfMyWindow, HandleOfWord)`.

The background of my question is that we have lots of code built around a system where we have installed a macro in Word that when started from a button on the ribbon sends a message to our app to tell it to create a given window and show it inside of Word. This window can then insert text etc. into Word by using Word as a OLE Automation server. This has worked fine for the most part for many years. It still is, but occasionally the window is displayed far out of the visible area of Word. For example it can be 900 pixels to the right of the right edge of Word. It can often be found by making Word very wide across multiple monitors. The problem is only there on multi monitor systems. It is often affected by how our app and Word is placed on the monitors. It might also be affected by what monitors is set as the main monitor.

Our app is made using Delphi creating standard win32 exe's. The problem might have gotten worse after we started using VCL Styles.

I have tried placing our window using Windows API SetBounds and SetWindowPos, just the top and left properties of the form, and some other things. It just never pops up where I think my code is telling it to. Most of the time it is visible and all is well, but still at another position than I set. I just can figure out any system to where it is placed.

However, when writing this I found something that might be relevant, but still no solution:

1. https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4882-a-big-and-very-strange-bug-with-high-dpi-vcl-style-and-form-constraints/
2. From SetParent documentation: "Unexpected behavior or errors may occur if hWndNewParent and hWndChild are running in different DPI awareness modes."

Comment: Simply put don't do this. Use a COM addin. You no chance of making this work robustly.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you could try to use [Object Linking and Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oleds/85583d21-c1cf-4afe-a35f-d6701c5fbb6f) framework, it allows you to embed certain objects/controls directly into your application.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know we should have done this different from the start, but would rather not do a rewrite. Maybe someday... You might very well be correct about it never allowing for a robust solution.

Acutally, it seems I have some success now making calls in this order: DefaultMonitor := dmDesktop; Position := poDesigned; MakeFullyVisible(); SetParent(); SetWindowPos().

But it is too early to say for sure yet. I have been here before, and usually something unexpected happens for some customers.

Comment: You can not just render the contents of your application window to another window that belongs to a completely different application. Why? Because if you do try to do so you end up with two threads (each belonging to its own application) interacting with the same window so you end up with bunch of race conditions that could wreak havoc. This is actually the same as to why you should not be accessing your UI from secondary threads directly as that could also lead to race conditions between your main and the secondary thread.

Comment: SilverWarior, while the concept is far from perfect, race conditions has not been a problem for the 20 years it has been in use. It is not set up for race conditions like you describe. It is just the placement of windows that is a problem that needs to be solved. 

It seems sometimes the full desktop (spanning across all monitors) makes up the coordinate system, sometimes the full monitor of Word, and somtimes just the window of Word. GetWindowRect on the Word window allways gives consistent numbers, but when using those numbers they might relate to any of the three coordinate systems used.